# Descargar archivos desde aplicacion android

Tags: android, webservice

Estoy intentando hacer que mi aplicacion pueda descargar archivos que se encuentran en un servidor mediante una URL o URI, el problema es que no lo he conseguido, he seguido un ejemplo de internet pero solo puedo descargar imagenes y yo quiero que se pueda descargar diferentes tipos de archivos como pdf, rar, zip, apk etc... Pero no lo he logrado, he intentado usando diferentes ejemplos pero no me han funcionado del todo.

En el ultimo ejemplo del que me guie es el siguiente:

Primero declaro dos variables:

> private DownloadManager mgrex = null;
>
> private long lastDownload = -1L;

Luego con mi botón ejecuto el método downloadFile():

```
public void downloadFile(){
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://webService/descargas/20180819.pdf");

        Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                .mkdirs();

        lastDownload=
                mgrex.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                        .setTitle("Ejemplo")
                        .setDescription("Descargando...")
                        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                "20180819.pdf"));
    }

    public void queryStatus(View v) {
        Cursor c=mgrex.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(lastDownload));

        if (c==null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Download not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            c.moveToFirst();

            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_ID: "+
                    c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR: "+
                    c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP: "+
                    c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_LOCAL_URI: "+
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_STATUS: "+
                    c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)));
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "COLUMN_REASON: "+
                    c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)));

            Toast.makeText(this, statusMessage(c), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Con este metodo veo las descargas en el dispositivo:

```
    public void viewLog(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
    }
```

Aqui reviso que mensaje me esta devolviendo la descarga

```
 private String statusMessage(Cursor c) {
        String msg="???";

        switch(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))) {
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                msg="Download failed!";
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                msg="Download paused!";
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                msg="Download pending!";
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                msg="Download in progress!";
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                msg="Download complete!";
                break;

            default:
                msg="Download is nowhere in sight";
                break;
        }

        return(msg);
    }
```

Y por ultimo creo el BroadcastReceiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

            }
        };
    BroadcastReceiver onNotificationClick=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Descarga finalizada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

NO he encontrado la forma de hacer que mi aplicación pueda descargar diferentes tipos de archivos.

Comment: Revisa este  [tutorial](https://androidclarified.com/android-downloadmanager-example/) viene información muy detallada sobre la descarga de archivos

Comment: @TheVicShow ya habia revisado he intentado ese tutorial pero cuando quiero descargar archivos .mp4 u otro formato me los descarga mal, sin formato y pesando 0 kb